# Set correct data type with OpenAccess ORM Fluent API

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-open-access

I am using Telerik Data Access Fluent Model(Open Access) Code first approach for generating Database. Everything is going right except some issues.
•   I have created a Property as Decimal in code.  But in database its data type is numeric not decimal. I need to set data type as decimal but this is giving me numeric.
•   Same type of issue is there with Bool property in code that gives me tinyint as datatype in database instead bit. I also set the property as Boolean in C# code and generated column is still tinyInt. I need to set it as bit in database

Here are images for my properties and generated columns(From these properties in Database)

These are properties that are written in code
http://screencast.com/t/sOXOi3as0N

And this is the image of  generated table in database
http://screencast.com/t/9KmmEK1IL

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be the default behavior of the product - to map decimal CLR type props to columns of numeric SQL type and bool props to tinyint cols. You need to slightly change the mapping configuration for the package persistent type by specifying the correct SQL types for underlying columns mapped to these props in the following way:

```
mappingConfiguration.HasProperty(x => x.BasicPrice).HasColumnType("decimal").HasPrecision(18).HasScale(2); 
mappingConfiguration.HasProperty(x => x.IsActive).HasColumnType("bit");
```

Comment: is it possible to configure ColumnType in generell? I would like to change boolean type tinyint to bit but I'm unable to find something usefull in the docs...